# MySQL SELECT with LEFT JOIN and GROUP problem

Tags: php, mysql

I have a main table **foo** with dates and values, and a table **bar** with exception dates and values. If the date exists in the **bar** table, that value applies, otherwise the default **foo** value. So, for example:

```
foo
id  date        value
1   2009-11-19  25
2   2009-11-20  50

bar
id  date        value
1   2009-11-19  50
```

To select the right values I use the following type of query:

`SELECT
  f.date,
  IF (f.date = b.date, b.value, f.value) AS value
FROM foo f
LEFT JOIN bar b
  ON b.date = f.date`

This works fine. The date "2009-11-19" exists in **bar**, so it selects the 50-value. But now I'd like to GROUP the results by MONTH, using this query:

`SELECT
  MONTH(f.date) AS month,
  IF (f.date = b.date, b.value, f.value) AS value
FROM foo f
LEFT JOIN bar b
  ON b.date = f.date
GROUP BY month`

It now returns the results by month, so the grouping works fine. However, it now ignores the **bar** values, and it seems it doesn't do any matching at all. The total for the month is 75 (25 from foo + 50 from foo) instead of 100 (50 from bar + 50 from foo).

Is there a way to make this work? So that it selects the correct values if there's a match between both tables, and after that grouping it by month? I can use the first query and do the grouping in PHP afterwards, but I'd like to get the right results straight from MySQL if that's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a subquery, like so:

```
SELECT MONTH(date), value FROM 
    (SELECT
      f.date,
      IF (f.date = b.date, b.value, f.value) AS value
    FROM foo f
    LEFT JOIN bar b ON b.date = f.date)
GROUP BY month
```

Answer (score 0):

do the SELECT in a subquery and GROUP in the main query:

```
SELECT themonth, SUM(myvalue) FROM (
    SELECT
      MONTH(f.date) AS themonth,
      IF (f.date = b.date, b.value, f.value) AS myvalue
    FROM foo f
    LEFT JOIN bar b
      ON b.date = f.date) tmptable
GROUP BY themonth;
```

Comment: Why? This doesn't change the result. GROUP BY happens after the select is performed the first time, thus you are selecting the results from a derived table for no reason. If I'm missing something, fine, but I don't see the point of the subselect.